# Is there a place for prototypes in the Angular structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototype

I have several prototypes I have added to my project, but with the inclusion of Angular I'm not sure if they're better off in a separate file or if they fit easily into the Angular structure.

For instance:

```
    Array.prototype.sum = function sum() {
        var add = function(previous, current) {
            return previous + current;
        };

        return this.length ? this.reduce(add) : 0;
    };
```

It certainly works included in a separate file, but I was wondering if there's a better place for it.

Comment: IMO, the best place for such a thing is... nowhere. Don't mess with built-in types. If everybody did that, it would be a nightmare. The sum() function could be an agular service or even a simple helper function.

Comment: @JBNizet I do understand the concern with altering the prototype chain on native objects, however the theory is still applicable.  Creating a service seems like a lot of work because I would have to inject it into every context I want to use it in (which is pretty much every controller and factory/service I have.  I'd do it if that were the best way, I just don't know if that really is the best way to go about it.

Comment: As I said, just define it as a helper function in some globally available object (like angular does with the angular object, containing many reusable helper functions: toJson, fromJson, isArray, etc.).

Comment: When you start up your angularjs application, via bootstrap or in your main file, just insert that code there.

Comment: Just for a reference, extending native objects breaks encapsulation and other code that may rely on native objects bahaving in a certain manner may break. For now it's only the `for ... in someArray` that breaks when not checking `hasOwnProperty` but it's bad practise in general: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice.3A_Extension_of_native_prototypes